# I18n: my ransack search fields are not translated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, rails-i18n, ransack

I'm using ransack gem, and I'd like the form fields to be translated.

```
= search_form_for q
  = f.input :name_cont # I'm using simpleform gem for forms
```

Result:

[image]

As far as I understand, I would expect the search field's label to be something like "Name contains", right?

Do I manually have to load translation files? I also already manually added the ransack translation keys, but this didn't work, too.

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like this

```
<%= f.input :name_cont, label: t('your_path.field') %> <!-- your_path.field would be the translation -->
```

Comment: As far as I understand from the [docs](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#i18n), this should work out of the box?

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim Yes, so you can do like `t('ransack.attributes.person.name')`

Comment: I mean the following: when there are keys for ransack i18n like 'contains', then I would expect ransack to automatically generate a label like "Name contains" for a field `name_cont`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late, but if you are using simple_form with ransack, you can put your translation in **simple_form.en.yml**

and put it under

```
en:
  simple_Form:
    labels:
      defaults:
        name_cont: 'Name contains'
```